# I get a "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

When I do Analyze to find out the potential memory leak, I get a "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller" :

```
- (int)downloadUrlTofolder:(NSString *)url filename:(NSString *)name tryTime:(int)tryTime
{
    int result = 0;
     GetFtpService *ftpService = [[GetFtpService alloc] initwithUrlandOutPut:url output:name];

    //I have delete the code here, but problem is not solved.

    [ftpService release];  //the potential problem point to this line
    return result;
}
```

Below is the "initwithUrlandOutPut" method:

```
- (id)initwithUrlandOutPut:(NSString *)url output:(NSString *)o
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self.urlInput = url;
        self.outPath = o;
        self.success = [NSString stringWithString:@"success"];
        self.connected = nil;
    }

    return self;
}
```

And the interface:

```
@interface GetFtpService : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInputStream *networkStream;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *urlInput;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInputStream *fileStream;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *outPath;
@property int tryTime;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *success;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *connected;

- (id) initwithUrlandOutPut:(NSString *)url output:(NSString *)o;
```

I want to know why this happened? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because the 'w' in "initwith..." is not capitalized. Maybe the analyzer is not recognizing the method as an init method because of that.